# ElasticSearch to Kafka event - on each change using Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

End goal: To connect Elasticsearch and kafka and recieve ongoing change event in ES indexes to kafka. From kafka, I have listeners to do further processing.

Method: I used Logstash input and output plugins. Here is the configuration code.

```
input {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                index => "liferay-20116"
        }
}
output {
      kafka {
        topic_id => "elastic-topic-index"
        codec => json
      }
}
```

It is working but there is one weird issue.

When I listen to kafka it reads all the document from ES which is around 176 docs right now.

Once it reads, it stops for a while say 2 seconds and then read whole 176 docs again!

I don't know what is the issue, is this due to Logstash behavior or Kafka is acting weird?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to send incoming documents if the match a query?
 In this case look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behavior of this plugin - it push data matching to given query.  If you want to have only changed documents, the only workaround is to build this knowledge of what changed yourself - for example, you need to have timestamp for entries, and then incorporate this knowledge into query that is sent to ES.

Comment: So you mean its ElasticSearch input plugin which is pushing data i.e every 176 doc in say every 2 seconds to kafka? I think this should happen when there is any change in ES not every 2 seconds or so.

Comment: I don't know why plugin push every 2 seconds, but plugin just executes query - it doesn't know anything about what changed in ES.

Comment: Thanks. I actually figured it out. This is not gonna work for sure. Writing a blog post on same and will share :)

Answer (score 1):

I did figure it out without using Logstash.

I am using ElasticSearch plugin which emits events on every change as web socket.

Reference: https://codeforgeek.com/2017/10/elasticsearch-change-feed/